# $d(x,y) = | x^{2} - y^{2}|$ and $ d(x,y) = | x^{3} - y^{3}|$ are metrics on $\mathbb R$ or not$?$

Tags: metric-spaces

$d(x,y) = | x^{2} - y^{2}|$ and $ d(x,y) = | x^{3} - y^{3}|$ are metrics on $\mathbb R$ or not$?$

Clearly,

1. $d(x,x) = 0$
2. $d(x,y) = d(y,x)$
3. $d(x,y) ≥ 0$ , for all $x,y$ for both.

Now, for fourth axiom.

4. $d(x,z) = |x^{2} - z^{2}| = |x^{2} - y^{2} + y^{2} - z^{2}| ≤ |x^{2} - y^{2}| + |y^{2} - z^{2}| = d(x,y) + d(y,z)$

   Similarly,
   $d(x,z) = |x^{3} - z^{3}| = |x^{3} - y^{3} + y^{3} - z^{3}| ≤ |x^{3} - y^{3}| + |y^{3} - z^{3}| = d(x,y) + d(y,z)$

So both should be metrics. But answer is given that only the second one in metric. So what's wrong with my proof. I think something is wrong with my proof of fourth axiom.
I've just started metric spaces today.

Please suggest..

Comment: $d(-1,1)=0$ in the first case and to be a distance (not a "matrix"!) you want $d(x,y)=0 \iff x = y$ and not just $d(x,y)=0 \Leftarrow x = y$

Comment: Metrics are positive *definite*, meaning that $d(x,y) = 0 \iff x=y$.

Comment: The first axiom states $d(x,y) = 0$ if and only if $x = y$. Right$?$ I didn't pay attention to "if and only if" condition.

Comment: The first condition 1)  is not *just* $d(x,x) = 0$ but that if $x\ne y$ then $d(x,y) \ne 0$.  Clearly $|(-x)^2 - x^2|=0$ but $x \ne -x$ (if $x\ne 0$) so $d(x,y) = |x^2 - y^2|$ is not a metric.

Comment: [Which properties must a function, $f$, fulfill for $d(x,y)=|f(x)-f(y)|$ to be a metric](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/965818/which-properties-must-a-function-f-fulfill-for-dx-y-fx-fy-to-be-a) answers all your questions: $d(x,y) = |f(x) - f(y)|$ is a metric exactly if $f$ is  *injective.*

Comment: I removed the discussion about the plural of metric. If anyone cares to get to the bottom of it, possibly this can be asked on one of the language sites.

Answer (score 4):

You misstated the first condition.

As stated

1) $d(x,x) = 0$ is not strong enough.

The condition should be

2) $d(x,y) = 0 \iff x = y$.

If $d(x,y) = |x^2 - y^2|$ then $d(-x, x) = |(-x)^2 - x^2| = 0$ but if $x \ne 0$ then $x \ne -x$ so the condition does not hold.

So $d(x,y) = |x^2 - y^2|$ is not a metric.

.......

But if $d(x,y) = |x^3 - y^3|$ then

$|x^3 - y^3| = 0 \iff x^3 - y^3 = 0\iff x^3 = y^3$. Since we are talking of $\mathbb R$ and not complex numbers and as $3$ is odd it is okay to assume that $x^3 = y^3\iff x = y$.  If you are parsnickity you can prove that but that is really more detail than I think we need.[1]

So $d(x,y) = |x^3 - y^3|$ satisfies condition 1).

.........

Conditions 2,3 are trivial.

And condition 4) you did okay.

So $d(x,y)=|x^3 - y^3|$ is a metric.

Note:  Conditions 2,3,4 are all true for $d(x,y)= |x^2 - y^2|$ as well for the exact same reasons.  It's only condition 1 that fails.  But that's enough.

=========

[1] It's enough to assume that for any positive number $b > 0$ there is *exactly* one positive $c$ so that $c^n = b$. and that  $[(\pm) c]^n = (\pm -1)^n b$ so if $n$ is odd then $b$ and $-b$ have exactly one $n$th root that is the same sign as $b$ or $-b$ is.  If $n$ is even then $-b$ has *no* $n$th roots and $b$ has two, a positive and negative root, both equal in magnitude to $|c|$.

So for $n =3$ then  $x^3 = y^3 \iff x= y$ is an okay conclusion.

But for $n = 2$ then $x^2 = y^2 \iff |x| = |y| \iff x = y$ ***OR*** $x = -y$ is the only conclusion we can reach.  And that isn't a good enough conclusion.

Answer (score 2):

Recall the definition of a metric. A function $d: X \to \mathbb{R}$ on a space $X$ is a metric if:

1) $d(x,y) = 0$ if and only if $x=y$.

2) $d(x,y) =d(y,x)\ \forall\ x,y \in X.$

3) $d(x,y) \le d(x,z) + d(y,z) \ \forall \ x,y,z \in X.$

Now we check above conditions on two of our metrics:

Case 1 : $d(x,y) = |x^2-y^2|$.

$(i)\ d(x,y) = 0 \Rightarrow |x^2-y^2| = 0 \Rightarrow x^2-y^2 = 0 \ (\text{as modulus is always} \ge 0) \Rightarrow x^2 =y^2.$
So any $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x^2 =y^2$ gives $d(x,y) = 0.$ This contradicts our first condition for a metric. Hence $d(x,y) = |x^2-y^2|$ is not a metric on $\mathbb{R}$.

Case 2 : $d(x,y) = |x^3-y^3|$.

$(i)\ d(x,y) = 0 \Rightarrow |x^3-y^3| = 0 \Rightarrow x^3 - y^3 = 0 \Rightarrow (x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2) = 0 \Rightarrow x = y$ (as second term is never zero under the condition given). The other side is trivial as if $ x= y $ then $d(x,y) = |x^3-y^3| = 0$.

$(ii)\ d(x,y) = |x^3-y^3| = |y^3-x^3| = d(y,x).$

$(iii)\ d(x,y) = |x^3- y^3| = |x^3-z^3+ z^3-y^3| \le |x^3- z^3|+ |z^3-y^3|$ (by the triangular inequality in modulus.)
$\Rightarrow d(x,y) \le d(x,z)+d(z,y). $

Hence $d(x,y) = |x^3-y^3|$ is a metric on $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space and let $f: X\longrightarrow X$ be an injective map. Then: $$d_f(x, y)=d(f(x), f(y)),$$ defines a new metric in $X$. In fact:

- $d_f(x, y)=0\Leftrightarrow d(f(x), f(y))=0\Leftrightarrow f(x)=f(y)\Leftrightarrow x=y$ (here is where we used $f$ is injective;
- $d_f(x, y)=d(f(x), f(y))=d(f(y), f(x))=d_f(y, x)$;
- Given $x, y, z\in X$ we have $$d_f(x, z)=d(f(x), f(y))\leq d(f(x), f(z))+d(f(z), f(y))=d_f(x, z)+d_f(y, z).$$

This will show $d(x, y)=|x^3-y^3|$ is in fact a metric. The another one is not a metric as already pointed out.